# Why won't my Flask function return a JSONified array?

Tags: python, json, flask

I have:

```
@application.route('/prediction', methods=['POST'])
def create_predictions():
    ...
    print(alternatives)
    print(jsonify(alternatives, 201))

    return jsonify(alternatives, 201)
```

`alternatives` is a list of strings. When I print the `jsonify`, I get:

```
<Response 8800 bytes [200 OK]>
```

When I post data to the endpoint, I get `{}` as a response. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the status code should be passed outside of the jsonify call.
`return jsonify(alternatives), 201`

Comment: If `alternatives` is a list of strings like `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`, then this should be returning something like `[["a","b","c","d"],201]`...which is exactly what it does when I try running your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judgin from the `<Response 8800 bytes [200 OK]>` that you get i think you're using `requests.get(url)` to get the response. Or you're trying to print it which you can't so just try to actually request it

Instead try using this to see the returned json:

```
import requests
requests.get(url).json()
```

And also the status code is suppposed to returned outside the parentheses like this:

```
return jsonify(alternatives), 201
```

Comment: Getting `NameError: name 'url' is not defined`

Comment: Yes you have to define a variable named url that contains the url that you want e.g:
`url = "https://google.com"
requests.get(url).json()`